# Reset array of images to default image

Tags: javascript, reset

I have a game where the user has to guess two pair of similar playing cards to win. I want to be able to reset all images (the images display front face of a playing card) to the back image, once the game is over.

In the var reset, I tried a few ways to do that task (they are commented out). Could you guys give me a hint which one is the closest to the right solution?

Thanks

```
//var cards = ["queen", "queen", "king", "king"];
var cards = [
            {rank: "queen", suit: "hearts", cardImage: "images/queen-of-hearts.png"},
            {rank: "queen", suit: "diamonds", cardImage: "images/queen-of-diamonds.png"},
            {rank: "king", suit: "hearts", cardImage: "images/king-of-hearts.png"},
            {rank: "king", suit: "diamonds", cardImage: "images/king-of-diamonds.png"}
];

var cardsInPlay = [];

var checkForMatch = function() {
  if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
      alert("You found a match!");
  } else {
      alert("Sorry, try again.");
  }
};

var flipCard = function() {
  var cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
  this.setAttribute('src', cards[cardId].cardImage);
  console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);
  cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
  console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
  console.log(cards[cardId].suit);

  var cardsToPlay = 2;
  if (cardsInPlay.length === cardsToPlay) {
  checkForMatch();
  }
};

var createBoard = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
    cardElement.setAttribute('src', "images/back.png");
    cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
    cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
    document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
  }
};

var reset = function() {
  cardsInPlay.length = 0;
  //for (i = 0; i < cardsInPlay.length; i++) {
    //document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('src', "images/back.png");
    //var board = document.getElementById('img');
    //board.setAttribute('src', "images/back.png");
    //var parent = document.getElementById('game-board');
    //var child = document.getElementById('img');
    //parent.removeChild(child);
    //var board = document.querySelector('game-board');
    //board.parentNode.removeChild(board);
    //createBoard();
};

createBoard();

var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', reset);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your code this should do it:

```
var reset = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    //you had img here
    document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].setAttribute('src', "images/back.png"); 
  }
};
```

I think you're confusing `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName`. In order for getElementById to work the id attribute needs to be set on a particular html node (and it needs to be unique on the page). getElementsByTagName will get all elements on the page of a particular tag name (img in this case). If I've missed something, post a fiddle or direct me to your complete code.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` returns an array. You cannot call `setAttribute` method on an array.

Comment: Great! consider accepting this answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getElementsByTagName` instead of `getElementById` to get the `img` tag elements.

**NOTE:** The below solution assumes that the images are only for the game. In case you happen to have any other images in your HTML, everything they too will get affected.

**QUICK SOLUTION**

```
const imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(let i=0; i<imgElements.length; i++) {
  imgElements[i].setAttribute("src", "images/back.png");
}
```

**BETTER SOLUTION**

If you want to isolate the images you use in your game you can do something like this in your render.

```
var createBoard = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    .
    .
    .
    cardElement.setAttribute('data-type', 'game-card-image')
    .
    .
    .
  }
};
```

And then select based on the `data-type` like below

```
const imgElements = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-type='game-card-image']");

for(let i=0; i<imgElements.length; i++) {
  imgElements[i].setAttribute("src", "images/back.png");
}
```